# In WordPress, is there a way to display the number of results that would be returned if a taxonomy is applied to a search?

Tags: php, wordpress

On the WordPress search page I have a sidebar with all the terms associated with the post type the search has been performed on. Each of the terms have a checkbox next to them.

I want to be able to show the number of results that would be returned if I applied the term to the current set of results.

So, lets say I search all the posts for the word 'blog' and I get 100 results. I might have something like this in the sidebar...

### Category

[ ] Tech (50)

[ ] Sport (33)

[ ] Gaming (7)

[ ] Other (10)

The only thing I have got which will do this is to run a WQ_Query for each term with the same search terms originally searched along with the term applied to the search. I ask for a single result (which seems to speed things up) and then I echo $query->found_posts which gives me the total number of results.

This works fine, but it does mean I have to run a WP_Query for every single term which seems incredibly inefficient. Does anyone have a better approach which will achieve the same result?

Comment: A combination of GROUP BY the category and COUNT would be a more effective way to do this in SQL, but WP_Query doesn’t have an easy way to introduce a GROUP BY clause. But if your current filter is based on assembling the query using WP_Query and its methods, it’d probably not be that easy to rewrite that completely to a self-written statement. You can get the actual statement via the `request` property though, so perhaps you could take that as basis, and insert the necessary extra parts via string manipulation …?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's the code you are using to output the sidebar? We need more information to help. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)